# Apply per column matrix multiplication using a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $\mathbf{X}$

$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
       (x^{(1)})^T\\[0.3em]
       (x^{(2)})^T\\[0.3em]  
       \vdots \\[0.3em]
       (x^{(N)})^T\\[0.3em]   
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       x^{(1)}_1 & x^{(1)}_2 & \dots & x^{(1)}_N\\[0.3em]
       x^{(2)}_1 & x^{(2)}_2 & \dots & x^{(2)}_N\\[0.3em]  
       \vdots   & & & \vdots\\[0.3em]
       x^{(N)}_1 & x^{(N)}_2 & \dots & x^{(N)}_N\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$$ and the vector $\mathbf{x}$
$$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
       y_1 \\[0.3em]
       y_2 \\[0.3em]
       \vdots  \\[0.3em]
       y_N  \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it possible to use an already defined product (e.g. *Kronecker* $\otimes$, *Khatri-Rao product* $\odot$ or *Hadamard product* $\ast$) between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ in order to define the matrix bellow?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
       y_1 x^{(1)}_1 & y_1 x^{(1)}_2 & \dots & y_1 x^{(1)}_N\\[0.3em]
       y_2 x^{(2)}_1 & y_2 x^{(2)}_2 & \dots & y_2 x^{(2)}_N\\[0.3em]  
       \vdots   & & & \vdots\\[0.3em]
       y_N x^{(N)}_1 & y_N x^{(N)}_2 & \dots & y_N x^{(N)}_N\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you!!

Comment: If you allow constants, with $\mathbf 1 := (1,1,\ldots, 1)$, you can consider $(y \otimes \mathbf 1) * X$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks @martini, for reasons of curiosity can we have other alternative representations? For example, can we have this using the $vec$ operator? Thanks!